# Sistema de login en Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, login, lumen

Es mi primera experiencia con el framework Lumen (versión 5.4.5) y estoy teniendo problemas con el sistema de login.

En la documentación oficial no dice nada más allá de cómo obtener el usuario identificado en el sistema, y qué directivas descomentar en el fichero `bootstrap/app.php` para ello.

Sin embargo, no dice cómo funciona, dónde poner la lógica para ver si el usuario y la contraseña son correctos (ver en una tabla de una base de datos?, la contraseña está cifrada de alguna manera?,...).

Por tanto no consigo hacer el login.

Tengo las siguientes líneas descomentadas en el fichero `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
$app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

**¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?**